# Adding a category to UIImage in iPhone

Tags: iphone, linker, uiimageview, uiimage, categories

I want to add a category to UIImage and link it to my iPhone app, but I got this error:

> (unrecognized selector)

My code: `DoingStuff.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (DoingStuff)

- (UIImage *)performStuff;

@end
```

DoingStuff.m

```
#import "DoingStuff.h"

@implementation UIImage (DoingStuff)

- (UIImage *)performStuff 
{
    // My code here
}

@end
```

But when I run my program I get this :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView performStuff:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b415d0'

Comment: what does it mean "link"? Is the category put inside a static library?

Comment: No, i want just to use the new category with my program to doing some stuff on UIImage.

Comment: Have you read my answer? Seems likely that you just haven't added the `import` statement in your calling class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[UIImage performStuff]; // Correct call
```

not

```
[UIImageView performStuff]; // It is a UIImage category not UIImageView
```

for starters.

So you would do something like this...

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test"];
[image performStuff];
```

Comment: -1: Not sure why this is getting votes. He clearly coded an instance method, not a class method. Your "correct call" is blatantly invalid.

Comment: @jordan is using class method syntax to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the category is in the target project just include the DoingStuff.h. If inside a static library the linker will not link it in, because it doesn't know it should link objective c objects it doesn't know will be used.

You need to put one of -all_load, -force_load or -ObjC in other linker options in you target project. Different people report some or all of them make linker work. Starting with XCode 4 -ObjC should be enough.

That said I didn't have success with any of them and ended in adding the categories from the library to the target project as references.

**EDIT**

Just saw my mistake, probably it gets linked but is a instance method and you are calling it as a class method:

not

```
[UIImage performStuff];
```

but

```
UIImage *image = <your image>;
[image performStuff];
```

Comment: Thanks, Jordan answer my question.

Comment: @iPadNewbie: What!? How did an incorrect answer "answer your question"?

Answer (score 0):

According to how you have your category set up, you would then need to call it like this:

```
UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage"];
[myImage performStuff];
```

Additionally, you aren't following the naming conventions for categories. Your class name should be something more like "`UIImage+DoingStuff.h". I would suggest refactoring it so that it's more clear to others that it's a category.

And of course, you need to import the header file into the class you want to use it in:

```
#import "DoingStuff.h"
```